# Use `Dynamic[]` to plot dynamically solve equation and dynamically display calculated value

Tags: plotting, dynamic, interactive

Here is my code and it works well:

```
{Slider[Dynamic[a], {-5, 5}], Dynamic[a]}
{Slider[Dynamic[b], {-5, 5}], Dynamic[b]}
Dynamic[Plot[Evaluate[y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 25, y]], {x, a, b}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```

after moving sliders output like:

[image]

So first slider  (`a` variable) shows start value on the `x` axis, and second slider (`b`) shows end value on `x` axis. Now I need also to display dynamically start and end values of `y` axis outside of the plot (it maybe separate cell with `Dynamic[]`). How Can I add it? Please provide solution with `Dynamic[]` and not `Manipulate[]`.

Comment: Will Epilog work?

Comment: @Kuba Thank you for asking. Yes, but if you know simpler solution it will be preferable. My goal is just do interactive plots as fast as possible for my personal use in order to better understand math. I do not need good styling, faster and easier way is preferable.

Comment: If you want to display additional numbers on the axis then try Epilog + Text/Inset.

Comment: Doesn't removing the `PlotRange` option get you what you want?  A dynamically resizing plot.

Comment: @Edmund No, I need fixed sized plot. I need to also display dynamically calculated values. And those vales can be located at any place, not on the plot itself (I edited and corrected my question)

Comment: @Kuba  I need to display dynamically calculated values (which will be values of y axis). Those vales can be located at any place, not on the plot itself (I edited and corrected my question).

Answer (score 1):

This I think works:

```
{Slider[Dynamic[a], {-5, 5}], Dynamic[a]}
Dynamic[Evaluate[y /. Solve[a^2 + y^2 == 25, y]]]
{Slider[Dynamic[b], {-5, 5}], Dynamic[b]}
Dynamic[Evaluate[y /. Solve[b^2 + y^2 == 25, y]]]
Dynamic[Plot[Evaluate[y /. Solve[x^2 + y^2 == 25, y]], {x, a, b}, 
  AspectRatio -> Automatic, PlotRange -> {{-20, 20}, {-20, 20}}, 
  PlotLegends -> "Expressions"]]
```